# Swift: Save responseString ID to String

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Sending this code with HTTP POST returns an ID, but I'm so far unable to extract the ID from responseString and save it as it's own String in my app.

I'm looking into using Alamofire, perhaps that'll make things easier but I was hoping to be able to do it using just Swift code. Any help is appreciated.

```js
var parseError: NSError?

let date = NSDate()
let timeStamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URL)!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


let params = ["name":fullName.text, "number":phoneNumber.text, "email":emailAddress.text, "timeStarted":timeStamp] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: nil)

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    
    if error != nil {
        println("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    
    println("response = \(response)")
    
    let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("responseString = \(responseString)")
    
    let idFromServer = responseString?.valueForKeyPath("id") as String!
    println(idFromServer)
    var dateID = idFromServer
    newUser.setValue(dateID, forKey: "dateID")
```

Comment: responseString = Optional({"ok":true,"id":"cd24c6f69c8a7b85a77e979c230143ea","rev":"1-9ea56c3486e35bcd84bfd5d1bf05a8e8"}
)

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7fd98160f6f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.'